# What's the standard way of set child views' size and position?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom viewgroup which extends relativelayout and I have several components in side of it. Because of the bad performance of nested weight layout, I decide to set child views' size and position programmatically. For now, I use xml to create the view and subviews and then set the position and size of some of them programmatically as below.

```
private void assignProperSizeToChildren(int x, int y) {
    int cardWidth = x / 3;
    int cardHeight = y / 3;
    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) bgView1.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.topMargin = (int)(y / 4 * (1 - val));
    layoutParams.height = cardHeight;
    layoutParams.width = cardWidth;
    LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (LayoutParams) bgView2.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams2.topMargin = (int)(y / 4 * (1 - val));
    layoutParams2.height = cardHeight;
    layoutParams2.width = cardWidth;
    LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (LayoutParams) bgView3.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams3.topMargin = (int)(y * 3 / 8 * (1 - val));
    layoutParams3.height = cardHeight;
    layoutParams3.width = cardWidth;
    bgView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    bgView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
    bgView3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
    bgView1.setPivotY(y / 2);
    bgView2.setPivotY(y / 2);
    bgView3.setPivotY(y / 2);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.bg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams1.topMargin = y / 6;
    layoutParams1.bottomMargin = y / 6;
    layoutParams1.leftMargin = x / 6;
    layoutParams1.rightMargin = x / 6;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams4 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) receiveProgress.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams4.width = cardWidth;
    receiveProgress.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);
    layoutParams4 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) sendProgress.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams4.width = cardWidth;
    sendProgress.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);
    name.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, y / 7);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int x = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int y = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    assignProperSizeToChildren(x,y);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

It seems to work but the view behaves strangely when I want to do an animation.

```
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float val = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) bgView1.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.topMargin = (int) (getMeasuredHeight() / 4 * (1 - val));
            bgView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (LayoutParams) bgView2.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams2.topMargin = (int) (getMeasuredHeight()  / 4 * (1 - val));
            bgView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
            LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (LayoutParams) bgView3.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams3.topMargin = (int) (getMeasuredHeight()  / 4 * (1.5 - val));
            bgView3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
            invalidate();
        }
    });
```

I found that every time I changed the layoutparams of the child views, `onMeasure()` get called and the value changes. Also, the animation does not work at all. Therefore, I wonder if this is the standard(right) way to create a custom viewgroup.
Thank you very much!

Comment: In viewgroup's `onMeasure`, you should call each child's `measure` to let them measure themselves. And you can override viewgroup's `onLayout` in which you can call each child's `layout`.

Comment: I am now using translation to do the animation and the problem seems to disappear